# Pick user's choice on button click

Tags: c, gtk

I need to pick the user's choice and store the value in a global variable then after the user has chosen the `vbox` with the buttons should disappear and control be returned to `create_window()`. I don't know if it is the best method for such a task.

```
#include "test.h"

int number_players;

void create_window() {

    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "test");
    gtk_window_maximize (GTK_WINDOW (window));
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

    get_number_players(window);

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
    G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    g_print("%d\n", number_players);

    gtk_main();

}

void get_number_players (GtkWidget *window) {

    GtkWidget *vbox, *button_choice1, *button_choice2, *button_choice3;

    vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);

    button_choice1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("six Players");
    button_choice2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Seven Players");
    button_choice3 = gtk_button_new_with_label("nine Players");

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), button_choice1);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), button_choice2);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), button_choice3);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button_choice1), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(read_choice), GINT_TO_POINTER(6)); 
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button_choice2), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(read_choice), GINT_TO_POINTER(7));
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button_choice3), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(read_choice), GINT_TO_POINTER(9));
}

void read_choice (GtkWidget *window, gpointer data) {

    number_players = GPOINTER_TO_INT(data);
}

void destroy (GtkWidget *window, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}
```

From some reason the global variable `number_players` is not printed correclty if I print in `read_choice` though I can see the right value.

Comment: what do you mean is not printed correctly.  What is your print statement?  What is the output?  What do you mean by "I can see the right value"?

Comment: Why do you have `g_print("%d\n", number_players);` before `gtk_main();`? This will print '0' as value, because global variables usually get that value by default. You are printing the value of the variable before  `gtk_main()` has been run, that is why you can't see the correct value. That is also why you get the correct result if you print it inside `read_choice()`.